# How to pre-fill $ID Check fields in Docusign API?

Tags: docusignapi

Does anyone know how to pre-fill $ID Check fields in Docusign API? I can't find any relevant information in API guide. The guide only lists a way on how to prefill the template.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "pre-fill $ID Check fields"?  The ID Check is a process where the user goes through and answers security sensitive information that helps identify the individual before they open/view the envelope.  What fields are you trying to pre-fill?

Comment: I am trying to pre-fill "idCheckInformationInput" field, which contains street address and other personal information of the signer. That way the signer does not have to fill the information again, that they have filled on our site. Unfortunately the field exists only as part of "recipients" array and not part of "templateRoles".

Comment: This is what I want to accomplish:

1. User registers on our site. 
2. User fills out personal data including mailing/home address.
3. We send to user Docusign envelope generated from a template. ID Check fields are pre-filled with address data from our website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This Answer contains a SOAP Fragment and a Complete REST Call in JSON with Headers, Body and the two templates with tabs needed for to execute the JSON body. The multi-part form body is used so that when you add inline templates and documents with dynamic pdf bytes you are already setup.

SOAP Documentation for IDCheck at 
DocuSign [http://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Sending Group/IDCheckInformation.htm?Highlight=IDCheckInformationInput](http://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Sending%20Group/IDCheckInformation.htm?Highlight=IDCheckInformationInput)

Live DocuSign SOAP Help for methods, parameters and data model and methods at DocuSign https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx

REST Documentation for IDCheck at DocuSign [http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST API References/Recipients/Signers Recipient.htm?Highlight=IDCheckConfigurationName](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Recipients/Signers%20Recipient.htm?Highlight=IDCheckConfigurationName)

Live DocuSign REST Help for methods, parameters and data model and methods at DocuSign https://www.docusign.net/restapi/help

---

**Via SOAP (fragment part of recipient)**

SOAP – XML (Not REST / XML(key values are different))

```
        <Recipients>
           <Recipient>
              <ID>1</ID>
              <UserName>David Grigsby</UserName>
              <Email>dgrigsbyds+idcheck@gmail.com</Email>
              <Type>Signer</Type>
              <AccessCode/>
              <RequireIDLookup>true</RequireIDLookup>
              <IDCheckConfigurationName>ID Check $</IDCheckConfigurationName>
                                         <IDCheckInformationInput>
                                                        <AddressInformationInput>
                                                                       <AddressInformation>
                                                                                      <Street1>104 Bremen Dr</Street1>
                                                                       </AddressInformation>
                                                                       <DisplayLevel>Editable</DisplayLevel>
                                                        </AddressInformationInput>
                                                        <DOBInformationInput>
                                                                       <DisplayLevel>Editable</DisplayLevel>
                                                        </DOBInformationInput>
                                         </IDCheckInformationInput>                 
              <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
              <Note/>
              <SignInEachLocation>false</SignInEachLocation>
           </Recipient>
```

Sample of above XML as a IDCheck Result at box: https://docusigninc.box.com/s/u4pj47lwom01h0clbjcn

---

**via REST (Complete JSON using Composite Template and Form model with two template)**

You will need to use the two templates below, save as xml, upload templates and then replace below with the new template ids, and add your two different emails

I like to use Google Chrome with Postman to send REST or SOAP calls when prototyping.

Here are the two resulting signed documents from the envelope from my below example at box
Doc

DocA [box] https://docusigninc.box.com/s/cm1bf67prdoxmzoue8wd

DocB [box] https://docusigninc.box.com/s/1yl7rbjny61o3rfzv2t1

```
POST /restapi/v2/accounts/YourExternalAccountId/envelopes HTTP/1.1
Host: demo.docusign.net

HEADERS:
--------

X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"yourEmail","Password":"YourPassword","IntegratorKey":"YourIntegratorKey"}
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AAA
Accept: application/json

BODY:
--------

--AAA
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data

{
        "emailSubject": "Test 3",
        "emailBlurb": "Using two templates from composite template structure",
        "status": "sent",   
        "compositeTemplates": [{
               "serverTemplates": [{
                       "sequence": "1",
                       "templateId": "YourTemplateID1"
               }],
               "inlineTemplates": [{
                       "sequence": "1",
                       "recipients": {
                              "signers": [{
                                      "email": "youremail1@domain.com",
                                      "name": "your name (1)",
                                      "recipientId": "1",
                                      "roleName": "Role",
                                      "requireIDLookup": "true",
                                      "idCheckConfigurationName": "Check $",
                                      "idCheckInformationInput" : {
                                        "addressInformationInput" : 
                                        {
                                            "addressInformation" :
                                            {
                                                "street1" : "123 main street"
                                            },
                                            "displayLevelCode" : "Editable"
                                        },
                                        "dobInformationInput" : 
                                        {
                                            "displayLevelCode" : "Editable"
                                        }

                                      },                                      
                                      "tabs": {
                                             "textTabs": [{
                                                     "value": "YourName",
                                                     "tabLabel": "name"
                                             },
                                             {
                                                     "value": "YourFirstName",
                                                     "tabLabel": "first_name"
                                             }]
                                      }
                              }]
                       }
               }]
        },
        {
               "serverTemplates": [{
                       "sequence": "2",
                       "templateId": "YourTemplateID2"
               }],
               "inlineTemplates": [{
                       "sequence": "2",
                       "recipients": {
                              "signers": [{
                                      "email": "youremail2@domain.com",
                                      "name": "Your Name (2)",
                                      "recipientId": "1",
                                      "roleName": "Role",
                                      "tabs": {
                                             "textTabs": [{
                                                     "value": "Your Name (2)",
                                                     "tabLabel": "name"
                                             },
                                             {
                                                     "value": "YourLastName",
                                                     "tabLabel": "last_name"
                                             }]
                                      }
                              }]
                       }
               }]
        }]
}


--AAA--
```

### **Template1**

Template XML at [box] https://docusigninc.box.com/s/dru41hdcgo9cqffqxzi4

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EnvelopeTemplate xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
    <EnvelopeTemplateDefinition>
        <TemplateID>82b2ce36-c6d1-41e5-9eb7-8c0d2b349057</TemplateID>
        <Name>A Simple</Name>
        <Shared>true</Shared>
        <TemplatePassword />
        <TemplateDescription />
        <LastModified>2014-02-25T19:57:01.337Z</LastModified>
        <PageCount>1</PageCount>
    </EnvelopeTemplateDefinition>
    <Envelope>
        <AccountId>6918840b-91f3-464a-a219-74df4df172a1</AccountId>
        <Documents>
            <Document>
                <ID>1</ID>
                <Name>a.pdf</Name>
                <PDFBytes>removed</PDFBytes>
            </Document>
        </Documents>
        <Recipients>
            <Recipient>
                <ID>1</ID>
                <UserName />
                <Email />
                <Type>Signer</Type>
                <AccessCode />
                <RequireIDLookup>false</RequireIDLookup>
                <SAMLAuthentication>
                    <SAMLAttributes />
                </SAMLAuthentication>
                <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
                <Note />
                <RoleName>Role</RoleName>
                <TemplateLocked>false</TemplateLocked>
                <TemplateRequired>false</TemplateRequired>
                <SignInEachLocation>false</SignInEachLocation>
            </Recipient>
        </Recipients>
        <Tabs>
            <Tab>
                <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
                <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
                <XPosition>211</XPosition>
                <YPosition>63</YPosition>
                <ScaleValue>1</ScaleValue>
                <Type>Custom</Type>
                <Name>name</Name>
                <TabLabel>name</TabLabel>
                <Value />
                <CustomTabType>Text</CustomTabType>
                <CustomTabWidth>174</CustomTabWidth>
                <CustomTabHeight>11</CustomTabHeight>
                <CustomTabRequired>true</CustomTabRequired>
                <CustomTabLocked>false</CustomTabLocked>
                <CustomTabDisableAutoSize>false</CustomTabDisableAutoSize>
                <CustomTabValidationPattern />
                <CustomTabValidationMessage />
                <TemplateLocked>false</TemplateLocked>
                <TemplateRequired>false</TemplateRequired>
                <SharedTab>false</SharedTab>
                <RequireInitialOnSharedTabChange>false</RequireInitialOnSharedTabChange>
                <ConcealValueOnDocument>false</ConcealValueOnDocument>
                <Bold>false</Bold>
                <Italic>false</Italic>
                <Underline>false</Underline>
            </Tab>
            <Tab>
                <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
                <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
                <XPosition>214</XPosition>
                <YPosition>98</YPosition>
                <ScaleValue>1</ScaleValue>
                <Type>Custom</Type>
                <Name>first_name</Name>
                <TabLabel>first_name</TabLabel>
                <Value />
                <CustomTabType>Text</CustomTabType>
                <CustomTabWidth>174</CustomTabWidth>
                <CustomTabHeight>11</CustomTabHeight>
                <CustomTabRequired>true</CustomTabRequired>
                <CustomTabLocked>false</CustomTabLocked>
                <CustomTabDisableAutoSize>false</CustomTabDisableAutoSize>
                <CustomTabValidationPattern />
                <CustomTabValidationMessage />
                <TemplateLocked>false</TemplateLocked>
                <TemplateRequired>false</TemplateRequired>
                <SharedTab>false</SharedTab>
                <RequireInitialOnSharedTabChange>false</RequireInitialOnSharedTabChange>
                <ConcealValueOnDocument>false</ConcealValueOnDocument>
                <Bold>false</Bold>
                <Italic>false</Italic>
                <Underline>false</Underline>
            </Tab>
            <Tab>
                <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
                <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
                <XPosition>71</XPosition>
                <YPosition>142</YPosition>
                <ScaleValue>1</ScaleValue>
                <Type>SignHere</Type>
                <Name>Sign Here</Name>
                <TabLabel>Signature 3</TabLabel>
                <Value />
                <TemplateLocked>false</TemplateLocked>
                <TemplateRequired>false</TemplateRequired>
                <Bold>false</Bold>
                <Italic>false</Italic>
                <Underline>false</Underline>
            </Tab>
        </Tabs>
        <Subject>Please DocuSign this document: a.pdf</Subject>
        <EmailBlurb />
        <SigningLocation>Online</SigningLocation>
        <AutoNavigation>true</AutoNavigation>
        <EnvelopeIdStamping>true</EnvelopeIdStamping>
        <AuthoritativeCopy>false</AuthoritativeCopy>
        <Notification>
            <Reminders>
                <ReminderEnabled>false</ReminderEnabled>
                <ReminderDelay>0</ReminderDelay>
                <ReminderFrequency>0</ReminderFrequency>
            </Reminders>
            <Expirations>
                <ExpireEnabled>true</ExpireEnabled>
                <ExpireAfter>120</ExpireAfter>
                <ExpireWarn>0</ExpireWarn>
            </Expirations>
        </Notification>
        <EnforceSignerVisibility>false</EnforceSignerVisibility>
        <EnableWetSign>true</EnableWetSign>
        <AllowMarkup>false</AllowMarkup>
        <AllowReassign>true</AllowReassign>
        <BrandId>c949b06b-5530-410e-b20b-12b3e5376957</BrandId>
    </Envelope>
</EnvelopeTemplate>
```

### **Template2**

Template XML at link [box] https://docusigninc.box.com/s/hf3c03br9tpvntjatffl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EnvelopeTemplate xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
    <EnvelopeTemplateDefinition>
        <TemplateID>f1a039c0-61d2-4983-a889-4a2d0fd9802d</TemplateID>
        <Name>B Simple</Name>
        <Shared>true</Shared>
        <TemplatePassword />
        <TemplateDescription />
        <LastModified>2014-02-25T19:58:36.1Z</LastModified>
        <PageCount>1</PageCount>
    </EnvelopeTemplateDefinition>
    <Envelope>
        <AccountId>6918840b-91f3-464a-a219-74df4df172a1</AccountId>
        <Documents>
            <Document>
                <ID>1</ID>
                <Name>b.pdf</Name>
                <PDFBytes>removed</PDFBytes>
            </Document>
        </Documents>
        <Recipients>
            <Recipient>
                <ID>1</ID>
                <UserName />
                <Email />
                <Type>Signer</Type>
                <AccessCode />
                <RequireIDLookup>false</RequireIDLookup>
                <SAMLAuthentication>
                    <SAMLAttributes />
                </SAMLAuthentication>
                <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
                <Note />
                <RoleName>Role</RoleName>
                <TemplateLocked>false</TemplateLocked>
                <TemplateRequired>false</TemplateRequired>
                <SignInEachLocation>false</SignInEachLocation>
            </Recipient>
        </Recipients>
        <Tabs>
            <Tab>
                <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
                <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
                <XPosition>211</XPosition>
                <YPosition>63</YPosition>
                <ScaleValue>1</ScaleValue>
                <Type>Custom</Type>
                <Name>name</Name>
                <TabLabel>name</TabLabel>
                <Value />
                <CustomTabType>Text</CustomTabType>
                <CustomTabWidth>174</CustomTabWidth>
                <CustomTabHeight>11</CustomTabHeight>
                <CustomTabRequired>true</CustomTabRequired>
                <CustomTabLocked>false</CustomTabLocked>
                <CustomTabDisableAutoSize>false</CustomTabDisableAutoSize>
                <CustomTabValidationPattern />
                <CustomTabValidationMessage />
                <TemplateLocked>false</TemplateLocked>
                <TemplateRequired>false</TemplateRequired>
                <SharedTab>false</SharedTab>
                <RequireInitialOnSharedTabChange>false</RequireInitialOnSharedTabChange>
                <ConcealValueOnDocument>false</ConcealValueOnDocument>
                <Bold>false</Bold>
                <Italic>false</Italic>
                <Underline>false</Underline>
            </Tab>
            <Tab>
                <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
                <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
                <XPosition>214</XPosition>
                <YPosition>97</YPosition>
                <ScaleValue>1</ScaleValue>
                <Type>Custom</Type>
                <Name>last_name</Name>
                <TabLabel>last_name</TabLabel>
                <Value />
                <CustomTabType>Text</CustomTabType>
                <CustomTabWidth>174</CustomTabWidth>
                <CustomTabHeight>11</CustomTabHeight>
                <CustomTabRequired>true</CustomTabRequired>
                <CustomTabLocked>false</CustomTabLocked>
                <CustomTabDisableAutoSize>false</CustomTabDisableAutoSize>
                <CustomTabValidationPattern />
                <CustomTabValidationMessage />
                <TemplateLocked>false</TemplateLocked>
                <TemplateRequired>false</TemplateRequired>
                <SharedTab>false</SharedTab>
                <RequireInitialOnSharedTabChange>false</RequireInitialOnSharedTabChange>
                <ConcealValueOnDocument>false</ConcealValueOnDocument>
                <Bold>false</Bold>
                <Italic>false</Italic>
                <Underline>false</Underline>
            </Tab>
            <Tab>
                <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
                <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
                <XPosition>71</XPosition>
                <YPosition>142</YPosition>
                <ScaleValue>1</ScaleValue>
                <Type>SignHere</Type>
                <Name>Sign Here</Name>
                <TabLabel>Signature 3</TabLabel>
                <Value />
                <TemplateLocked>false</TemplateLocked>
                <TemplateRequired>false</TemplateRequired>
                <Bold>false</Bold>
                <Italic>false</Italic>
                <Underline>false</Underline>
            </Tab>
        </Tabs>
        <Subject>Please DocuSign this document: a.pdf</Subject>
        <EmailBlurb />
        <SigningLocation>Online</SigningLocation>
        <AutoNavigation>true</AutoNavigation>
        <EnvelopeIdStamping>true</EnvelopeIdStamping>
        <AuthoritativeCopy>false</AuthoritativeCopy>
        <Notification>
            <Reminders>
                <ReminderEnabled>false</ReminderEnabled>
                <ReminderDelay>0</ReminderDelay>
                <ReminderFrequency>0</ReminderFrequency>
            </Reminders>
            <Expirations>
                <ExpireEnabled>true</ExpireEnabled>
                <ExpireAfter>120</ExpireAfter>
                <ExpireWarn>0</ExpireWarn>
            </Expirations>
        </Notification>
        <EnforceSignerVisibility>false</EnforceSignerVisibility>
        <EnableWetSign>true</EnableWetSign>
        <AllowMarkup>false</AllowMarkup>
        <AllowReassign>true</AllowReassign>
        <BrandId>c949b06b-5530-410e-b20b-12b3e5376957</BrandId>
    </Envelope>
</EnvelopeTemplate>
```

Comment: David, would that work with an Envelope that is generated from a template? I tried something similar already and Docusign servers are ignoring the objects.

Comment: Yes, I will add a sample by EOD - One REST, One SOAP

Comment: David, this is genius. Thank you for your help. There is one small bug, the sequence # needs to be changed for InlineTemplates as they need to be ahead of the ServerTemplates. Once I changed that, it worked like a charm.

Comment: vbaranov - Most Welcome!

Correct, if adding Document bytes in the inline template you will need to orient the sequence number to situation :-)

Comment: **Rules of thumb:**
- If documents are only available via one of the templates in a composite, then sequence order is not critical for document inclusion.
- If a template within a composite has a dependency on another template, sequence order probably matters
- If using an inlineTemplate to match or map tabs by partial specification, be sure to always use the * wildcard in the tabLabel, even if fully specifying the tabLabel value.

Comment: I know this is pretty old, but I see the original question mentioned templateRoles although the answer doesn't.  

We currently use templateRoles for a pretty lengthy docuSign flow, and would be hard to completely restructure. Just adding the idCheckInformationInput to the templateRoles doesn't seem to work, is there a way to add it without completely restructuring? 

I'm currently trying:
.../v2/accounts/someId/envelopes 
data => {
   ....
   "templateId":"x",
   "templateRoles":[{
         ...
         "roleName":"Client",
         "tabs":{...},
         "idCheckInformationInput":{...}
}]}

Answer (score 0):

In case some needs this for C#...

```
 new Recipient
            {
                Email = email,                    
                Type = RecipientTypeCode.Signer,
                RequireIDLookup = true,
                IDCheckConfigurationName = "ID Check $",
                IDCheckInformationInput = new IDCheckInformationInput()
                {
                    AddressInformationInput = new AddressInformationInput()
                    {
                        AddressInformation = new AddressInformation() { 
                        City = city, 
                        State = state, 
                        Street1 = address,
                        Zip = zip }
                    },
                    DOBInformationInput = new DOBInformationInput() 
                    { 
                        DOBInformation = new DOBInformation() 
                        { 
                             DOB = dob
                        } 
                    },
                    SSN9InformationInput = new SSN9InformationInput() 
                    { 
                        SSN9Information = new SSN9Information()
                        {
                            SSN9 = ssn
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that in PHP, it seems that you have to add the API Model to each one of the values like below. Took me a while to figure out so I thought I would share.

```
    $signer1 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer([
        'email' => $customer->email, 
        'name' => $customer->fullName(),
        'role_name' => "Signer1",
        'recipient_id' => 1,
        'tabs' => [
            'textTabs' => 
                [
                     ['tabLabel' => 'Signer1_FullName',
                     'value' => $Signer1_FullName
                     ],
                     ['tabLabel' => 'Signer1_MailingAddress',
                     'value' => $Signer1_MailingAddress
                     ],
                ]

        ],
        'require_id_lookup' => "true",
        'client_user_id' => 1,

        // "id_check_configuration_name" => 'ID Check $',

        "id_check_information_input" => new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\IdCheckInformationInput([
              "address_information_input" => new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\AddressInformationInput([
                "address_information" => new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\AddressInformation([
                   "street1" => $customer->address,
                   "city" => $customer->city,
                   "state" => $customer->state,
                   "zip" => $customer->zip_code,
                ]),
                "display_level_code" => "Editable",
                "receive_in_response" => false
              ]),
              "dob_information_input" => new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\DobInformationInput([
            //  "dateOfBirth" => "sample string 1",
                "display_level_code" => "Editable"
              ]),
              "ssn9_information_input" => new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Ssn9InformationInput([
            //  "ssn9" => "",
                "display_level_code" => "Editable"
              ])
          ]),



    ]);
```