# Pre-filling $ID Check issues

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to send an envelope from a single 3rd party template that has "ID Check $" required for signers (second signer is not required so I'm using only one). We need to pre-fill both the envelope tabs AND the ID Check fields for embedded signing. We have a sender account with the template shared but can't alter it.

Referring to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22004668/2704696

**I'm using demo.docusign.net.**

The tabs and idCheckInformationInput are well formed but

If I use the same sequence number like this:

```
"serverTemplates": [{
   "sequence": "1"
   , "templateId": "MyTemplateID"
   }],
"inlineTemplates": [{
    "sequence": "1"
    , ...
```

I get the template fields pre-filled but the ID Check ones empty.

If I use

```
"sequence": "2"
```

for the serverTemplate, I get the ID Check filled but the tabs are not filled anymore.
Getting inline sequence > than server sequence results in empty ID Check fields as well.

Is it possible I need to update my JSON request somehow or how do I test the issue to find out the cause?

Test envelope id is e89ced0b-7da8-409b-aae3-06349d1605a2 if that helps someone from the DocuSign team. Can provide a full request if needed but that's a lot of JSON.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like DocuSign has an issue where the idCheckInformationInput data conflicts with a checked “Sender Cannot Edit Recipient” option in the template.

So far we were able to pass the idCheckInformationInput values successfully when the said recipient option is disabled. In case it's enabled, the ID Check screen does not get filled with the passed values.

No estimate on the fix yet.

**Source: Discussion with DocuSign enterprise support.**