# Pre-populating user's ID Check - Personal Information in DocuSign when using templateRoles

Tags: docusignapi

I'm currently using the rest api (.../v2/accounts/someId/envelopes) to request a users document. My app currently requests a document that has a corresponding template, with most of the data on that pre-filled using the templateRoles key. When users are prompted for an ID Check they are again asked information that we already have (name, address ect). We would like to have this information pre-filled.

I have looked through the documentation but none of the examples for idCheckInformationInput use templateRoles. Ideally we would not have to change the structure of the current api call since it is quite mature and well tested. I have tried adding the idCheckInformationInput key, but the ID Check is still returned blank.

Our current call is:

.../v2/accounts/someId/envelopes

```
data => {
   "allowMarkup":false,
   "allowReassign":false,
   "allowRecipientRecursion":false,
   "asynchronous":false,
   "authoritativeCopy":false,
   "autoNavigation":false,
   "brandId":"xxxx",
   "compositeTemplates":null,
   "customFields":null,
   "emailBlurb":"",
   "emailSubject":"Secure Authorization Document",
   "enableWetSign":false,
   "enforceSignerVisibility":false,
   "envelopeIdStamping":false,
   "eventNotification":{
      "envelopeEvents":[
         {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"completed",
            "includeDocuments":false
         },
         {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"declined",
            "includeDocuments":false
         },
         {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"voided",
            "includeDocuments":false
         }
      ],
      "loggingEnabled":true,
      "includeCertificateWithSoap":false,
      "includeDocuments":false,
      "includeTimeZone":false,
      "includeSenderAccountAsCustomField":false,
      "recipientEvents":[

      ],
      "requireAcknowledgment":true,
      "signMessageWithX509Cert":false,
      "soapNameSpace":"",
      "url":"xxxx/external/signing/eventnotification",
      "useSoapInterface":false
   },
   "signingLocation":"Online",
   "status":"sent",
   "templateId":"xxxx",
   "templateRoles":[
      {
         "accessCode":null,
         "clientUserId":"xxxx",
         "email":"xxxx@xxxx.com",
         "emailNotification":null,
         "name":"a a a",
         "recipientId":"1",
         "roleName":"Client",
         "tabs":{
            "checkboxTabs":[
               {
                  "name":"Checkbox",
                  "selected":false,
                  "tabLabel":"ExchangeEtcEmployed"
               },{...}
            ],
            "radioGroupTabs":[

            ],
            "textTabs":[
               {
                  "name":"Text",
                  "tabLabel":"\\*DOB",
                  "value":"1/1/1980"
               }, {...}

            ]
         },
         "idCheckConfigurationName": "ID Check $",
         "idCheckInformationInput":{ //new key possibly in the wrong spot
            "addressInformationInput":{
               "addressInformation":{
                  "street1":"aaa",
                  "street2":"",
                  "city":"San Francisco",
                  "state":"CA",
                  "zip":"94102"
               },
               "displayLevelCode":"Editable"
            },
            "dobInformationInput":{
               "dateOfBirth":"1/1/1980",
               "displayLevelCode":"Editable"
            },
            "ssn4InformationInput":{
               "ssn4":"4444",
               "displayLevelCode":"Editable"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I've also noticed that if I add requireIdLookup: true, and turn off the flag on docusign's side (manage -> template -> roles -> Identify -> Identity Check = ID Check $) no ID check shows up. The only way to get it to show up is to check that, and it is always returned empty.

### EDIT:

I have more recently tried to use the format specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000579/how-to-pre-fill-id-check-fields-in-docusign-api) but with the same results as before:

```
{
   "allowMarkup":false,
   "allowReassign":false,
   "allowRecipientRecursion":false,
   "asynchronous":false,
   "authoritativeCopy":false,
   "autoNavigation":false,
   "brandId":"xxxx",
   "compositeTemplates":[
      {
         "inlineTemplates":[
            {
               "sequence":"1",
               "recipients":{
                  "signers":[
                     {
                        "accessCode":null,
                        "clientUserId":"xxxx",
                        "email":"xxx@xxx.com",
                        "emailNotification":null,
                        "name":"a a a",
                        "recipientId":"1",
                        "roleName":"Client",
                        "tabs":{
                           "checkboxTabs":[...],
                           "radioGroupTabs":[...],
                           "textTabs":[...]
                        },
                        "idCheckInformationInput":{
                           "addressInformationInput":{
                              "addressInformation":{
                                 "street1":"aaa",
                                 "street2":"",
                                 "city":"San Francisco",
                                 "state":"CA",
                                 "zip":"94105"
                              },
                              "displayLevelCode":"Editable"
                           },
                           "dobInformationInput":{
                              "dateOfBirth":"1/1/1980",
                              "displayLevelCode":"Editable"
                           },
                           "ssn4InformationInput":{
                              "ssn4":"xxxx",
                              "displayLevelCode":"Editable"
                           }
                        },
                        "requireIdLookup":true,
                        "idCheckConfigurationName":"ID Check $"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ],
         "serverTemplates":[
            {
               "sequence":"1",
               "templateId":"xxx"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "customFields":null,
   "emailBlurb":"",
   "emailSubject":"Secure Authorization Document",
   "enableWetSign":false,
   "enforceSignerVisibility":false,
   "envelopeIdStamping":false,
   "eventNotification":{...},
   "signingLocation":"Online",
   "status":"sent",
   "templateId":null,
   "templateRoles":null
}
```

### Edit2:

I was able to get it to work-ish with the compositeTemplates format, although I had to remove the roleName. With the roleName set to "Client" it strictly follows what is defined in the Roles section of the template for "Client" (recipients and routing modal), and ignores the passed requireIdLookup key as well as any idCheckInfromationInput. Removing the role also stops any of the document's inputs from being filled with the tabs data--which makes sense considering the tags are role specific.

Ideally I could use the templateRoles version, but I would be happy with the compositeTemplates working with a role. You should be able to specify ID Check $ under the Identify column in the roles modal for a given template, and then have that ID Check filled in if you pass in idCheckInfromationInput.

Comment: I have tried it with and without "requireIdLookup" :"true", both ways display a blank idCheck. requireIdLookup is specified on a per templet level on docusign's site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this to work I needed to switch to the compositeTemplates format, and to get passed the issue with the roleName I had to UNCHECK "Sender Cannot Edit recipient" in the cog dropdown for the recipients and routing modal that is launched when you click on the roles for a template [image].

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the idCheckInformationInput is in the right spot, however you are missing the idCheckConfigurationName and requireIdLookup entries. Please check the documentation snippet below and small sample below:

https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Recipients/Signers%20Recipient.htm?Highlight=idCheckInformationInput

```
"name":"a a a",
"recipientId":"1",
"roleName":"Client",
 ...
"requireIdLookup" :"true",
"idCheckConfigurationName": "ID Check $",
  "idCheckInformationInput": {
    "addressInformationInput": {
      "addressInformation": {
        "street1": "sample string 1",
        "street2": "sample string 2",
        "city": "sample string 3",
        "state": "sample string 4",
        "zip": "sample string 5",
        "zipPlus4": "sample string 6"
      },
      "displayLevelCode": "sample string 1",
      "receiveInResponse": "sample string 2"
    },
```

Comment: I've tried it with both of those, the requireIdLookup is defined on DocuSign depending on which template is requested, so it shouldn't be added here (although I tried it to make sure that didn't make it work somehow). The ID check shows up regardless, so that shouldn't matter, it just isn't filled out. Also how did you decide on the idCheckConfigurationName of "ID Check $"? Does that need to match something specific? If it is just supposed to be that, that doesn't help. 

You can see in the docs that it isn't nested under templateRoles like mine is, although I don't have a signers section.

Comment: It needs to match the name of the authentication you want to use (ID Check, SMS, Phone, etc). You can see the name of the authentication options if you login to the web console and try to create an envelope with auth. The default idCheckConfigurationName for Lexis Nexis authentication is "ID Check $".

Comment: I thought that might have been it, but that is the ID Check name we are using and added that doesn't fix it. Thanks though.

Comment: Sort of got it working by removing the defined roleName and switching to compositeTemplates format, although that naturally broke other things (pre-filled template inputs and pre-configured ID Check toggle).